# Revert color curve modification having original/modified pair

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gimp, filter

So, I have this image, which has a filter applied: nothing fancy, it's just a reduction of blue intensity and maybe some temperature raise (I took a screenshot with Twilight enabled on my phone). If I have two identical images, one with the filter and one without, can I generate the curves' difference, and apply the filter backwards? How? I have Photoshop CS6 (and GIMP).

I know some quality is going to be lost, and I can probably do it by hand. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it, and catch the opportunity to learn something useful.

Comment: Helle the question seems a bit unclear to me. Do you want the inverse of a curves adjustment or do you want to generate curves from 2 images? While its true that the later could be done in reverse, its just easier to invert the curves function.

Answer (score 1):

With Gimp, assuming the filter only does a curves-like processing:

Take the reference filtered picture, and make it match the reference unfiltered picture as explained in this [very nice tutorial](https://patdavid.net/2012/07/getting-around-in-gimp-more-color.html). This is applying the Curves tool on the filtered picture, but with some method...

When you apply the tool, Gimp saves the latest set of parameters automatically (you can also save them explicitly and give then a name).

[image]

Once you have done this open you target filtered image, start the Curves tool, and reapply the settings on it.